# C++ Operator Overloading : Function Return type & argument - reference to same object

Tags: c++

I came across the following snippet of code. This function has the argument out passed by reference and it returns out and the end of code with return type pass by reference again. I don't understand as to why this function needs a return type. If out is already pass by reference any changes in the function will be reflected in out. So what is the point of having a return type stream& here?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Fraction &f1)
{
    out << f1.m_numerator << "/" << f1.m_denominator;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: The operator should be used in chained application usage, that's why.

Comment: It is needed to use the `operator<<` sequentially: `std::cout << f1 << std::endl`. That is the equivalent of `operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, f1), std::endl)`.